# If $S_{\mu\nu\sigma} V^{\mu}V^{\nu}V^{\sigma} = T_{\mu\nu\sigma} V^{\mu}V^{\nu}V^{\sigma}$, then is it true $S_{\mu\nu\sigma} = T_{\mu\nu\sigma}$?

Tags: tensor-calculus

For any vector $V$, suppose that the following equality holds
$$
S_{\mu\nu\sigma} V^{\mu}V^{\nu}V^{\sigma} = T_{\mu\nu\sigma} V^{\mu}V^{\nu}V^{\sigma}
$$
for two tensors $S$ and $T$. Does it follow from this that
$$
S_{\mu\nu\sigma} = T_{\mu\nu\sigma}  ?
$$
How to show it? I think this is true but a proof is escaping me...

EDIT: Does it involve the symmetrization of the tensors?

Comment: The answer changes if $T$ and $S$ are symmetric or not. Are they symmetric?

Comment: Yes, it equates the fully symmetric pieces of the tensors.

Comment: They are not necessarily symmetric. Cosmas has given the answer I'm seeking, it sounds like $S_{\mu\nu\sigma}V^{\mu\nu\sigma} V^{\mu} V^{\nu} V^{\sigma} = T_{\mu\nu\sigma}V^{\mu\nu\sigma} V^{\mu} V^{\nu} V^{\sigma}$ implies only that the symmetric parts of these tensors are equal, $ie.$ $S_{(\mu\nu\sigma)} = T_{(\mu\nu\sigma)}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not true. For a simple example consider
$$S_{\mu\nu\sigma} = 0$$
while $T_{\mu\nu\sigma}$ has all components zero except for 
$$T_{013} = 1, \quad T_{103} = -1.$$
Then in both cases, the contraction with three copies of $V^\mu $ vanishes.